# GWT Read-only TextArea will not resize

Tags: gwt

GWT newbie here. I have found that when I make a TextArea read-only useful features such as dynamic expansion and even word-wrapping stops working. My intention was to move a string from one text area, append it some way to some more strings, and then add this string into my read-only TextArea. I have doing something like this:

```
    // Temporarily enable the field to set the value of the TextArea
    logTextArea.setEnabled(true);

    String remarks = // my string to add into the box
    if (remarks.length() > 0) {

        logTextArea.setEnabled.setValue(remarks);
    }
    // set read-only again
    logTextArea.setEnabled.setEnabled(false);
```

I also have to work out how many lines I now span and explicitly set the height of the box (via setVisibleLines()). I have now found that it does not word-wrap, so I've had to add some more horrible bodge-code to further split up this string.

So I'm writing code to emulate functionality that comes for free on a normal writable TextArea. Has anyone else found this issue after setting a text-field read-only? Is there another widget I could possibly use to display a list of read-only strings that will auto resize and auto wrap for me?

Many thanks for your time,

tom

Comment: Auto Word wrap is part of TextArea behavior, only if you need to disable the word Wrap feature of Text area then you need to specify "getElement().setAttribute("wrap","off");"

Answer (score 0):

Text Area is fine for re-sizing and auto word wrap, even you have your text
area as read only.

Tested now by creating a test project for gwt and it is working fine.

Also Word Wrap is the default behavior of Text area if you want to turn it off then you need to explicitly do this "getElement().setAttribute("wrap","off");